# MVT Differentiation

Tags: calculus

Can anyone help me with these

1. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $[4,6]$ and is such that $f(4) = 6$ and $f' \geq 2$ on
   $[4,6]$. Find the lowest possible value of $f(6)$.

I think the answer for the lowest possible value of $f(6)$ is $10$. Is it right?

1. Give a function $f$ that is differentiable on $\Bbb R$ and which has the following 3 properties, or explain why such a function can't exist: $f(1) = 3$, $f(3) = 8$, and $f'(x)\leq 2$ for all $x$.

Comment: It is right. It is $\geq 10$ by MVT. And you can easily construct an example for which it is $10$.

Comment: For the second question: what does the MVT tell you, if such a function existed?

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, you've done well in figuring out what the least value of $f(6)$ may be. By MVT, there is a point $4<t<6$ such that $$f'(t)=\frac{f(6)-f(4)}{6-4},$$ whence $$f(6)=f(4)+2f'(t)=6+2f'(t)\ge10.$$ A straight line shows us that $10$ is a feasible value.

For the second, use the same kind of reasoning to figure out the following:

> Let $f$ be differentiable on $[1,3]$, such that $f(1)=3$ and $f'\le 2$ on $[1,3]$. What is the highest possible value of $f(3)$?

Comment: for second part, is it F(3) <= 1?

Comment: See my updated answer for a better idea how to find that.

Comment: ok and i get f(3)<=7...

Comment: Yes, indeed. So, is it possible to have a function such as that described in the second part?

Comment: no because its given that f(3)=8?

Comment: Bingo! Nice job.

Answer (score 0):

As per mean value theorem : $f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ where c is any point in the close interval [a b]

Therefore :

$f' = \frac{f(6)-f(4)}{6-4} =2 $

$\Rightarrow  \frac{f(6)-6}{6-4} = 2$

$\Rightarrow = f(6)=6+4 =10$

Comment: It should be $\geq$ all the way. And it should be: for some point $c$ in $(a,b)$. Not every point in $[a,b]$.